# How to sample data look like bivariate moon?

Tags: r

[image]

Here is 300 points form bivariate moon shape. I want to reproduce these datas via R, but I didn't find suitable tools. 
There is one function called "shapes.two.moon" in R-package "clusterSim", but I found it generates arch instead of moon:

[image]

The difference here is moon has two sharp end, while arch keep the same radius.

Great thanks to anyone who know something about moon plot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)

moon_maker <- function(n = 1000, noise = 0.1,
                       x_center = 0, y_center = 0, radius = 1) {
  moon <- tibble(
    i = 1:n,
    x = x_center + radius * cos(pi * i/n) + rnorm(n, 0, sd = noise * radius),
    y = y_center + radius * sin(pi * i/n) + rnorm(n, 0, sd = noise * radius),
  )
  moon
}

ggplot(data = moon_maker()) +
  geom_point(color = "red", aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point(data = moon_maker(x_center = 0.75), aes(x, -y), color = "blue" )
```

[image]

Comment: That's seems better! ggplot create enough noise compare to "shapes.two.moon". Let's me try!Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using clustering algorithm based on density. I used the DBScan algorithm to do the example below.

- I used other data due to the lack of data availability or the possibility of adjusting a reproducible example.

```
library(dbscan) # for data
library(fpc)
library(dplyr)
data("moons")
plot(moons, pch=20)
```

[image]

```
df <- moons %>% 
  dplyr::filter(Y < 1)
plot(df, pch=20)
```

[image]

```
set.seed(1)
db <- fpc::dbscan(df, eps = 0.4, MinPts = 2)
plot(db, df, main = "DBSCAN", frame = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But this data set contain only 100 data points. I have to create enough samples look like two moons.

Comment: If you provide a fully reproducible example, I can do with the value of n high.